# EF weird behavior when debugging

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, mstest, code-first, entity-framework-6

I have a code first EF implementation and I have a service layer function `GetNavigations()` that creates the `IEnumerable<Navigation>`.

As I run my code and hits the breakpoint in my MVC view, I noticed that my debug pointer goes back inside the `GetNavigations()` when I try to access an object property. Why does it do that? Does it actually run my function over and over?

I'm also wondering why my test doesn't step into my function call unless i do a `result.Count()`.

View

```
<ul>
    @foreach (var menu1 in Model)
    {
        <li><a href="@menu1.Url" >@menu1.Text</a>
            @if (menu1.SubNavigations.Count > 0)
            {
                <div>
                    <ul>
                        @foreach (var menu2 in menu1.SubNavigations)
                        {
                            <li>
                                <a href="@menu2.Url" >@menu2.Text</a>
                            </li>
                        }
                    </ul>
                </div>
            }
        </li>
    }
</ul>
```

Test Method

```
        INavigationManager oNavMgr = CreateTarget();

        // does not step into
        var result = oNavMgr.GetNavigations(NavigationType.Main, false);

        // but it steps into when i do this.
        Assert.IsTrue(result.Count() > 0);
```

Controller

```
public class NavigationController : Controller
{

    IUnitOfWork m_oUnitOfWork = null;

    public NavigationController(IUnitOfWork oUoW)
    {
        m_oUnitOfWork = oUoW;
    }


    //
    // GET: /Navigation/

    public PartialViewResult List(NavigationType iId)
    {
        var topNavs = m_oUnitOfWork.NavigationManager.GetNavigations(iId);

        return PartialView(topNavs);
    }

}
```

Comment: How are u passing `result` to the view?

Comment: Added my controller code

Comment: Everything seems right from what you have given so far...

Comment: Hmm. It's hard to debug the code especially if you cant step through it. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In EntityFramework we have two type of query execution:

1. Immediate
2. Deferred

in the immediate execution the query will be executed immediately on the database

sample > `db.Foo.Where(f => f.bar == bar).ToList();`

and for deferred execution, when you call them nothing actually happens on database and only the query will be there and when you try to get data the query will be execute ob the database

sample >

```
var baz = db.Foo.Where(f => f.bar == bar); // no query execution on the database

baz.count(); // deferred execution on database
```

and all of these happens for optimization and better experience, only run query on database when it is necessary.

Comment: Now that makes sense! Thank you so much! But why can't I step into the function when I am debugging? Any idea?

Comment: this is just my opinion: i think when microsoft created Visual Studio they didn't considered this behavior in that time, for the future versions of Visual Studio maybe stepping back be an option